# displaying and uncovering letters using asterisks

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a hangman game that picks a random word from a text file and then displays the word as asterisks and has the user guess the letters of the word. If the user guesses correct then the letter gets uncovered and they keep guessing until they uncover the word. It will then display the number of misses and ask if the user wants to try to guess another word.

The problem I am having is when you try to guess the first letter in any word and guess it correctly it still says its incorrect and doesn't uncover the word.The other letters uncover but you then keep guessing forever because the first letter of the word can't be uncovered. I am not sure how to fix this

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char[] guessed = new char[26];
        char guess = ' ';
        char playAgain= ' ';

        int amountMissed = 0, index = 0;

        do
        {
            // initilization of word and testword so that we could generate a testword with the same length as original
            char[] word = RandomLine().Trim().ToCharArray();

            char[] testword = new string('*', word.Length).ToCharArray(); 
            char[] copy = word;

            Console.WriteLine(testword);
            Console.WriteLine("I have picked a random word on animals");
            Console.WriteLine("Your task is to guess the correct word");

             while (!testword.SequenceEqual(word)) 
             {
                try
                {
                    Console.Write("Please enter a letter to guess: ");

                    guess = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }

                bool right = false;
                for (int j = 0; j < copy.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (copy[j] == guess)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Your guess is correct.");
                        testword[j] = guess;
                        guessed[index] = guess;
                        index++;
                        right = true;
                    }
                }
                if (right != true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your guess is incorrect.");
                    amountMissed++;
                }
                else
                {
                    right = false;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(testword);

            }
            Console.WriteLine($"The word is {copy}. You missed {amountMissed} times.");
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Do you want to guess another word? Enter y or n: ");
                playAgain = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        } while (playAgain == 'y' || playAgain == 'Y');


        Console.WriteLine("Good-Bye and thanks for playing my Hangman game.");
    }
        public static string RandomLine()
    {

            // store text file in an array and return a random value
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("D:\\CPSC1012 ADV PORTFOLIO\\Advanced Portfolio\\Advanced1.csv");
            Random rand = new Random();
            return lines[rand.Next(lines.Length)];



    }
}
```

Comment: @sticky, if you read that linked question, I don't think it's *actually* the same problem (despite the fact it's from the same asker and about the same general topic). The linked question is about having too many asterisks in the hidden word, this one is about not being able to guess the first letter. I'm all for closing dupes but only if they're actually dupes. Otherwise, everyone's limited to one question each :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: Hmm, I have misunderstood it, now you're pointing it out. Retracting the close vote. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code works fine for me once I modify `RandomLine()` to just return `zebra` (since I don't have access to your words file).

So the *first* thing I would check is that your animal names are actually all lower case in that file. I note that, if I have it return `Zebra` instead, it exhibits the behaviour you describe when I try to guess the lower case `z`.

If that *is* the case, you just need to make your comparisons case-insensitive, something like modifying `RandomLine()` to ensure the word is all lower case:

```
return lines[rand.Next(lines.Length)].ToLower();
```

and this to ensure your guess is lower case:

```
guess = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine().ToLower());
```